# How to communicate batch project with Api project?

Tags: rest, spring-batch

I have two projects first one is called api project to launch a REST api webServices and the other
project is batch project that is responsible to execute batchs.

How can make the  batch project execute a rest api that exist in the api project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `newman` utility from Postman for `REST API` `batch project`.

'newman` is Javascript utility.
it can be use when production.

`postman` is UI based API testing utility when you develop a test logic.

Installing and running of [`newman`](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/installing-running-newman/)

It can test a REST-API service from linux terminal(windows and Max also possible).

You can test CRUD(Create/Read/Update/Delete = /Post/Get/Put/Delete) REST APIs by `newman`

### Demo

#### #1 test simple users web service for `API project`

`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
            "street": "Kulas Light",
            "suite": "Apt. 556",
            "city": "Gwenborough",
            "zipcode": "92998-3874",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-37.3159",
                "lng": "81.1496"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ervin Howell",
        "username": "Antonette",
        "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
        "address": {
            "street": "Victor Plains",
            "suite": "Suite 879",
            "city": "Wisokyburgh",
            "zipcode": "90566-7771",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-43.9509",
                "lng": "-34.4618"
            }
        },
        "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
        "website": "anastasia.net",
        "company": {
            "name": "Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Clementine Bauch",
        "username": "Samantha",
        "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
        "address": {
            "street": "Douglas Extension",
            "suite": "Suite 847",
            "city": "McKenziehaven",
            "zipcode": "59590-4157",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-68.6102",
                "lng": "-47.0653"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
        "website": "ramiro.info",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
            "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
            "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
        }
    }
    ... removed
 ]
```

#### Test by `newman` from linux terminal

It shows test result summary
I tested 3 unit tests

```
$ newman run 'Test Users API Service.postman_collection.json' 
newman

Test Users API Service

→ All users
  GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users [200 OK, 6.69kB, 773ms]
  ✓  Status code is 200
  ✓  Check the number of users
  ✓  Check the email of Bret
  ✓  Check the name of Bret
  ✓  Check the address of Bret

→ User 2
  GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2 [200 OK, 1.55kB, 205ms]
  ✓  Status code is 200
  ✓  Check the email of Ervin Howell
  ✓  Check the name of Ervin Howell
  ✓  Check the address of Ervin Howell

→ User 3
  GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/3 [200 OK, 1.56kB, 194ms]
  ✓  Status code is 200
  ✓  Check the email of Clementine Bauch
  ✓  Check the name of Clementine Bauch
  ✓  Check the address of Clementine Bauch

┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│                         │            executed │             failed │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│              iterations │                   1 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│                requests │                   3 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│            test-scripts │                   3 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│      prerequest-scripts │                   0 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│              assertions │                  13 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────┤
│ total run duration: 1253ms                                         │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ total data received: 6.67kB (approx)                               │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ average response time: 390ms [min: 194ms, max: 773ms, s.d.: 270ms] │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

### This is UI test section in `Postman`

It can develop a testing logic for each API during developing period.

[image]

#### This test logic

#1 Check response code

#2 Check number of users

#3 Check User name/email and address

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});

pm.test('Check the number of users', () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().length).to.equal(10);
});

let user = pm.response.json().find(a => a.username === 'Bret');

pm.test('Check the email of Bret', () => {
    pm.expect(user.email).to.equal("Sincere@april.biz");
});

pm.test('Check the name of Bret', () => {
    pm.expect(user.name).to.equal("Leanne Graham");
});

pm.test('Check the address of Bret', () => {
    pm.expect(user.address.street).to.equal("Kulas Light");
});
```

### running collection in Postman

it can filter test items and number of loop

[image]

Shows whole test steps and processing time
[image]

Also can debug in console view. you can put `console.log` message.
[image]